# Creating key value pairs using next two iterations in a for loop (PHP)

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I have an array of string values called $genderAge that looks like this when echoed:-

> F, 0-4, 327607378
>
> M, 0-4, 392700793
>
> F, 15-24, 887438943
>
> M, 15-24, 525132614
>
> M, 25-34, 621410857

So for the above array, $ageRange[0] is "F". $ageRange[1] is "0-4", and so forth.

I want to separate it out into two arrays, $male_array and $female_array with key value pairs. The key should be age range and the value should be cost.

```
    $male_array = [];
    $female_array = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($genderAge); $i++) {
        if ($genderAge[i] == 'M') {
            $male_array[$genderAge[i+1]] = $genderAge[i+2];
        }
        elseif ($genderAge[i] == 'F') {
            $female_array[$genderAge[i+1]] = $genderAge[i+2];
        }
    }

    foreach($male_array as $x => $x_value) {
        echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

The above doesn't echo anything. I want it to echo this:

> Key=0-4, Value=392700793
>
> Key=15-25, Value=525132614
>
> Key=25-34, Value=621410857

Comment: Is this supposed to be an Array: `F, 0-4, 327607378, M, 0-4, 392700793, F, 15-24, 887438943, M, 15-24, 525132614, M, 25-34, 621410857`? That is: `$arr = array("F"," 0-4", "327607378", "M", "0-4", "392700793", "F", "15-24", "887438943", "M", "15-24", "525132614", "M", "25-34", "621410857");`

Comment: Can you post your real array by printing it out? Also what expected outcome you want? post that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array is constantly a combination of 3 pairs : Gender, Age range, Cost, you may want to increment of each 3 pairs in your loop. It will save you from errors relative to out of array indexes :

```
<?php
    $GENDER_MALE    = 'M';
    $GENDER_FEMALE  = 'F';

    $genderAge      =   ['F', '0-4', '327607378', 'M', '0-4', '392700793', 'F', '15-24', '887438943', 'M', '15-24', '525132614', 'M', '25-34', '621410857'];
    $male_array     =   [];
    $female_array   =   [];
    $size           =   count($genderAge);

    # Format the male/female array
    for( $i = 0; $i < $size; $i += 3 ) {
        $gender     =   $genderAge[$i];     // M or F
        $ageRange   =   $genderAge[$i + 1]; // 0-4, 14-18, ...
        $cost       =   $genderAge[$i + 2]; // 897726, 10927, ...

        if( $gender == $GENDER_MALE ) {
            $male_array[$ageRange] = $cost;
        }
        else if( $gender == $GENDER_FEMALE ) {
            $female_array[$ageRange] = $cost;
        }
    }

    # Print the male/female formatted array
    foreach( $male_array as $key => $value ) {
        echo "Age range : $key - cost = $value <br />";
    }
?>
```

Notice in the first `for` loop the use of `$i += 3` which can be read as :

> Loop every 3 items on my array

This way, you can apply your index + n relative to the pair you need (`$i + 1` for the age range, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Your `$genderAge` should be an array of this kind so that you can perform storing of values in the separate variables and you can use it for further purpose.

**Proposed Array:**

```
$genderAge  = array("F", "0-4", "327607378", "M", "0-4", "392700793", "F", "15-24", "887438943","M", "15-24", "525132614","M","25-34", "621410857");
```

For Loop Manipulation over the array in order to save the value.

> Here you must use `$i` for increment operator with +1. You must not use the `i` along separately as you have used.

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
$genderAge  = array("F", "0-4", "327607378", "M", "0-4", "392700793", "F", "15-24", "887438943","M", "15-24", "525132614","M","25-34", "621410857");
$male_array = [];
$female_array = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($genderAge); $i++) {
    if ($genderAge[$i] == 'M') {
        $male_array[$genderAge[$i+1]] = $genderAge[$i+2];
    }
    elseif ($genderAge[$i] == 'F') {
        $female_array[$genderAge[$i+1]] = $genderAge[$i+2];
    }
}

echo 'M Values'.'<br>';
foreach($male_array as $x => $x_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
echo '<br>';
echo 'F Values'.'<br>';
foreach($female_array as $y=> $y_value) {
    echo "Key=" . $y . ", Value=" . $y_value;
    echo "<br>";
}
echo '<br>';
?>
```

**Output:**

```
M Values
Key=0-4, Value=392700793
Key=15-24, Value=525132614
Key=25-34, Value=621410857

F Values
Key=0-4, Value=327607378
Key=15-24, Value=887438943
```

Comment: LOL I can't believe I forgot that the "i" needed a dollar sign too. Such a rookie mistake. Thank you! :)

Comment: Glad to help you. If you find my solution is useful you may accept it so that it will help others too.

Comment: @Anant. You have explode and i have not used and i prefer it to be an array that it. Both of us are doing the same thing alone. I am writing extra code to print the value that's it.

Comment: @helpmeplz. Is this fair on your part. Hope so i have rectified your error but your awards are to the person who has delivered the solution after you got the output.

Answer (score 0):

> First, You may want to get all those key-value pairs including the Sex in an associative array, instead. Here's how that could be done using `for(){}` Loop:

```
    <?php

        $arr    = array("F"," 0-4", "327607378",
                        "M", "0-4", "392700793",
                        "F", "15-24", "887438943",
                        "M", "15-24", "525132614",
                        "M", "25-34", "621410857");

        $all    = array();
        for($a=0, $b=1, $c=2; $a <= (count($arr)-3); $a+=3, $b+=3, $c+=3){
            $temp = array(
                "sex"       => $arr[$a],
                "key"       => $arr[$b],
                "value"     => $arr[$c]
            );
            $all[] = $temp;
        }

        var_dump($all);
```

> The call to `var_dump($all);` yields:

```
        array (size=5)
          0 => 
            array (size=3)
              'sex' => string 'F' (length=1)
              'key' => string ' 0-4' (length=4)
              'value' => string '327607378' (length=9)
          1 => 
            array (size=3)
              'sex' => string 'M' (length=1)
              'key' => string '0-4' (length=3)
              'value' => string '392700793' (length=9)
          2 => 
            array (size=3)
              'sex' => string 'F' (length=1)
              'key' => string '15-24' (length=5)
              'value' => string '887438943' (length=9)
          3 => 
            array (size=3)
              'sex' => string 'M' (length=1)
              'key' => string '15-24' (length=5)
              'value' => string '525132614' (length=9)
          4 => 
            array (size=3)
              'sex' => string 'M' (length=1)
              'key' => string '25-34' (length=5)
              'value' => string '621410857' (length=9)
```

> Now, to echo out some data, you can just do something like this:

```
    <?php

        foreach($all as $iKey=>$arrKv){
            echo "sex : "   . $arrKv["sex"]     . "<br />"          . PHP_EOL;
            echo "Key : "   . $arrKv["key"]     . "<br />"          . PHP_EOL;
            echo "Value : " . $arrKv["value"]   . "<br /><br />"    . PHP_EOL;
        }
```

> The Compound Result of each of the `echo()` in the Loop above yields:

```
        sex : F
        Key : 0-4
        Value : 327607378

        sex : M
        Key : 0-4
        Value : 392700793

        sex : F
        Key : 15-24
        Value : 887438943

        sex : M
        Key : 15-24
        Value : 525132614

        sex : M
        Key : 25-34
        Value : 621410857
```